# What I am missing in this copy into

Tags: copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I loaded csv files into snowflake stage to copy data into table. My script runs with no error, but cero record is loaded.

My script is:

```
Create or Replace STAGE MYTestStage;
Create or Replace FILE FORMAT csv_format
TYPE = CSV
FIELD_DELIMITER = ‘|#|’
SKIP_HEADER = 1
NULL_IF =()
RECORD_DELIMITER = ‘|*|’
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE
Compression = none;

COPY INTO DEVELOPMENT.MY_TABLE
FROM @MYTestStage
FILE_FORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME =     csv_format TYPE = CSV   RECORD_DELIMITER = ‘|*|’   FIELD_DELIMITER = ‘|#|’ SKIP_HEADER = 1)
FORCE = TRUE;

LIST @MYTestStage

MYTestStage/Source_File_1.csv
MYTestStage/Source_File_2.csv
```

Comment: A sample of the first 4 or 5 rows of data would help diagnose. It appears that you are expecting data like Col1|#|Col2|#|Col3|*|Data1|#|Data2|#|Data3|*|   Note that since you defined a file format, you only need to specify the FORMAT_NAME parameter. The other parameters in your COPY INTO command are redundant.

Comment: What is showing in the query history for when the copy statement ran? Any rows processed, any errors, etc?